# My Spotify app won't open, can't be deleted and won't force quit on macOS

Tags: macos, imac, spotify

...and yet when I try to, a dialogue box tells me I can't delete it because it's already open.

Any ideas what I can do?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure Spotify isn't in your login items (System Preferences → Users & Groups) so it won't automatically start. Log out, making sure to uncheck ‘Reopen windows when logging back in’, then log back in. Try to delete the app now.

Comment: Many thanks for that grgarside. It worked. You're a genius (that, or I'm a fool!). Does your screen name have anything to do with the wonderful Scritti Politti, by the way?

Comment: @McCordMark No problem, welcome to Ask Different! If an answer solved your problem, you can mark it accepted using the check mark on the left. It's doesn't, it's [based on my name](https://georgegarside.com), but I am British though!